# Proof sketch verification: Given $f : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ with a special property, show that $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing, solution-verification

$
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\supp}{\mathrm{supp}}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand{\setb}[2]{\left\{ #1 \; \middle| \; #2 \right\}}
\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathcal{F}}
$
**The Problem:** Let $f : [0,1] \to \R$ be such that $\exists \ve > 0$ such, for any choice of finitely many distinct $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ in $[0,1]$,

$$\left| \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \right| \le \ve$$

Show that $\supp(f) := \setb{ x \in [0,1] }{ f(x) \ne 0 }$ is countable.

---

**Brief Overview & My Goal:** I have played with this problem a little bit, and have found it quite easy to show that $\supp(f)$ can be finite for some $f$, and sometimes $\supp(f)$ can be countably infinite. So the question remains: can $\supp(f)$ be uncountably infinite? Or, rather, what contradiction does that make?

So my goal in this approach was trying to do so via contradiction: suppose $f$ is such that $\supp(f)$ is uncountable, and see what contradiction arises. I think I found an approach where the boundedness of a finite sum is violated, but I wanted to make sure I have the right idea.

I will admit this proof does have some details that need fleshed out for this to be a "proper" proof (some statements are made without proof), but hopefully at least I have the overall "big picture" of what needs to be done.

Of course, if there are any logical flaws/inconsistencies, I would appreciate them being pointed out!

---

**My Approach So Far:**

By way of contradiction, suppose $\supp(f)$ as defined for an applicable $f$ is uncountable. Then $\FF := \set{ |f(x)| \mid x \in [0,1] }$ is nonempty trivially. Moreover, $\FF$ must be bounded above - otherwise, there will always exist some $x$ such that $|f(x)| > \ve$ for any $\ve > 0$. Since $\varnothing \ne \FF \subseteq \R$ is bounded above, then $M := \sup \FF$ exists, is positive, and is finite, due to the least-upper-bound property of $\R$. It thus holds that $M \in \FF'$ (the set of limit points of $\FF$), and thus $\exists \set{p_n}_{n \in \N}$ such that $|f(p_n)| \to M$.

Moreover, $\exists N \in \N$ such that the subsequence $\set{|f(p_n)|}_{n=N}^\infty \subseteq [M-\delta,M]$ for any given $\delta$. $(\ast)$

With this in mind, we will take a finite number of points $\set{x_i}_{i=1}^n$, where $x_i = p_{N+i}$. Note that the maximum element that $|f|$ outputs of this sequence, due to the monotonicity, is $|f(x_n)|=|f(p_{N+n})|.$ Then it holds
\begin{align*}
\abs{ \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) }
&\le \sum_{i=1}^n \abs{ f(x_i) } \tag{triangle inequality} \\
&\le \sum_{i=1}^n \abs{ f(x_n) } \tag{def. of maximum} \\
&= n \abs{ f(x_n) } \tag{simplify}
\end{align*}
Observe that, for $n$ sufficiently large, $nf(x_n) > \ve$, contradicting the notion that $f$ can satisfy the property for an uncountable $\supp(f)$.

---

**Potential Problems:**

- This feels overly complicated, for one ... I feel there is a more elementary solution, but I can't figure out what it is.
- I especially have doubts about the claim at $(\ast)$. I've tried a few ways to phrase what I'm trying to intuitively grasp while also being useful for breaking the bounds eventually: essentially, I want the sequence to eventually be within some certain distance of the supremum. (For instance, another I used at one point is that the sequence would be "eventually monotonic" after some $n=N$, but I don't think that's necessarily true. For instance, the sequence $1,0,1/2,0,1/3,0,1/4,\cdots$ converges to $0$ and is bounded below, but isn't monotonic.)

Of course I doubt these are the only problems ... any thoughts?

Comment: What do uncountable sums look like?

Comment: Integrals, generally, but the premise of the problem is for finite choices. (And finitely many distinct $x_i$ specifically, I forgot to specify.)

Comment: There is (at least) one flaw in your argument: $|\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)| \le n f(x_n)$ and $n f(x_n) > \epsilon$ does not result in a violation of $|\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Oh, good point. It would be more prudent to establish a lower bound on the value of the sum instead then. (At least if we were to use any similar approach.) Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Correct solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193014/how-to-prove-the-set-xfx-neq-0-is-at-most-countable

Comment: I see. I struggled to find the question on MSE anywhere, but I guess you're better with this sort of searching than me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with $|f(x)|$ is  a bad idea since inequalities go  the wrong way. You will have to consider positive and negative values of $f$ separately.

Let $A_n=\{x: f(x) \geq \frac 1  n\}$. Let us show that this is set is necessarily a finite set. If $x_1,x_2,...,x_N$ are distinct members of this set then $\epsilon \geq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} f(x_k) \geq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}  \frac  1n=\frac N n$. It follows that $N \leq n\epsilon$. Hence $A_N$ has at most $[n\epsilon]+1$ elements in it.

Let $A=\bigcup_N A_N$. Then $A$ is at most countable. If $x \notin A$ then  $f(x) <\frac 1 N$ for every $N$. Hence $x\notin A \implies f(x) \leq 0$. Similarly, we get another at most countable set $B$ such that $x\notin B \implies f(x) \geq 0$. It follows that $x\notin A\cup B \implies f(x)= 0$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: The questions asks for a *proof verification.* Otherwise we can close as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193014/42969.

Comment: Eh, I think the proof verification point is a bit moot for the same flaw you pointed out in the comments anyways, though the other solutions give me a means to at least get **a** solution. I could always just delete the question and come back with alternative trials if I want to re-salvage my own method.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I have added  a line to say why your approach doesn't work.